# Conda disk error despite having disk space

Tags: python, conda, diskspace

I am creating a conda env, i have multple filesystems with my home directory completely full. However I have space on other parts of the filesystem.

I am trying to create a conda env in an area where there is space, but keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 317, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 346, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 250, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "/apps/x86_64/software/Anaconda3/2021.05/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 713, in _execute
    raise CondaMultiError(tuple(concatv(
conda.CondaMultiError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded
```

I have set the env prefix with:

`conda create --prefix ./path_where_there_is_space python=3.9`

and also exported:

`export CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=path_where_there_is_space`

but still get the error.

Conda is clearly trying to put something in the full home directory, but I'm not sure what. Can anyone explain what should be set so that *nothing* ends up going in the home directory.

Comment: Unless you configured Conda to locate the package cache (`pkgs_dirs`) on a separate volume, that's probably still eating up space.